# Regex to extract pattern from text

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have a string that contains a bunch of function calls within it. I need to extract every occurrence of the VariableSet function call. Functions can appear in any order.  Here is an example:

```
parsedExpression = "VariableSet(b,  999)If(a = 0,"Black",SetColor(a,b,c))VariableSet("a"  ,1.573)    VariableSet(   c,-2387)"
```

I need to find every match that starts with "VariableSet(" and ends with the first close parenthesis that follows it. So, for the example above, I need a list like this:

```
VariableSet(b,  999)
VariableSet("a"  ,1.573)
VariableSet(   c,-2387)
```

I planned to use the code below but I have not been able to determine the correct regex pattern. The best I could come up with is "VariableSet(.*(?i:)\b)" but it does not produce the list above.

```
Dim matches As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(parsedExpression, "VariableSet\(.*(?i:\)\b)")

' Loop over matches.
For Each m As Match In matches
  ' Loop over captures.
  For Each c As Capture In m.Captures
    Dim varName As String = ""
    Dim varValue As String = ""
    Dim firstCommaPosition As Integer

    'For every VariableSet that was found do the following:
    'Parse the captured string to get the variable name and value
    varName = c.Value.Replace("VariableSet(", "").Replace(")", "")
    firstCommaPosition = varName.IndexOf(",")
    varValue = varName.Substring(firstCommaPosition + 1)
    varName = varName.Substring(0, firstCommaPosition).Replace("""", "")

    'Set the variable
    ce.Variables(varName) = ce.Evaluate(varValue)

    'Remove this instance of VariableSet() function from parsedExpression
    parsedExpression = parsedExpression.Replace(c.Value, "")
  Next
Next
```

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could provide the correct regex pattern.

Comment: Maybe this `VariableSet\([^)]*\)`

Comment: Wow, I hacked away at that for a couple hours and sln replies with a pattern that works in just a few minutes! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will help you:

```
    Dim strMatch As String = ""
    Dim strVar1 As String = ""
    Dim strVar2 As String = ""
    Dim strExpression As String = "VariableSet(b,  999)If(a = 0,""Black"",SetColor(a,b,c))VariableSet(""a""  ,1.573)    VariableSet(   c,-2387)"

    Dim rx As New RegularExpressions.Regex("VariableSet\((?<V1>.*?),(?<V2>.*?)\)", RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    Dim rxMatch As RegularExpressions.MatchCollection = rx.Matches(strExpression)
    For intI As Integer = 0 To rxMatch.Count - 1
        strMatch = rxMatch(intI).Value                  'VariableSet(b,  999)
        strVar1 = rxMatch(intI).Groups("V1").ToString   'b
        strVar2 = rxMatch(intI).Groups("V2").ToString   '  999
    Next
```

Comment: Thanks Dan for the pattern as well as the code to use the results! I learned something new here. Your solution is a vast improvement over my mess.

Answer (score 0):

`VariableSet\([^)]*\)` should be a direct replacement.
If you wanted to get fancy, all your code could be done using a single regex.

```
 #  VariableSet\((\s*"?\s*([^,")]*?)\s*"?\s*(?:,\s*"?\s*([^,")]*?)\s*"?\s*)?)\)    

 VariableSet
 \(                     # Open paren
 (                      # (1 start), Inside paren's
      \s* 
      "? \s* 
      ( [^,")]*? )           # (2), Var
      \s* 
      "? \s* 
      (?:
           ,                      # Comma
           \s* 
           "? \s* 
           ( [^,")]*? )           # (3), Value
           \s* 
           "? \s* 
      )?
 )                      # (1 end)
 \)                     # Close paren
```

Example input string:

```
VariableSet(b,  999)
VariableSet("a"  ,1.573)
VariableSet(   c,-2387)
VariableSet( , 999)
VariableSet( "aadsfasdf")
VariableSet(   )
```

Output matches ( Var / Value ):

```
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 12 , len 1 ) 
b  
 **  Grp 3 -  ( pos 16 , len 3 ) 
999  
----------------
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 35 , len 1 ) 
a  
 **  Grp 3 -  ( pos 40 , len 5 ) 
1.573  
----------------
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 63 , len 1 ) 
c  
 **  Grp 3 -  ( pos 65 , len 5 ) 
-2387  
----------------
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 86 , len 0 )  EMPTY 
 **  Grp 3 -  ( pos 88 , len 3 ) 
999  
----------------
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 108 , len 9 ) 
aadsfasdf  
 **  Grp 3 -  NULL 
----------------
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 136 , len 0 )  EMPTY 
 **  Grp 3 -  NULL
```